# how to increase space between bar and increase bar width in matplotlib

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, web-scraping, bar-chart, wikipedia

i am web-scraping a  wikipedia table  directly from wikipedia website and plot the table. i want to increase the bar width, add space between the bars and make all bars visible. pls how can i do? my code below

[image]

```
#########scrapping#########
html= requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_Nigeria")
bsObj= BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
states= []
cases=[]

for items in bsObj.find("table",{"class":"wikitable sortable"}).find_all('tr')[1:37]:
    data = items.find_all(['th',{"align":"left"},'td'])

    states.append(data[0].a.text)
    cases.append(data[1].b.text)
  
 ########Dataframe#########
table= ["STATES","CASES"]
tab= pd.DataFrame(list(zip(states,cases)),columns=table)
tab["CASES"]=tab["CASES"].replace('\n','', regex=True)
tab["CASES"]=tab["CASES"].replace(',','', regex=True)
tab['CASES'] = pd.to_numeric(tab['CASES'], errors='coerce')
tab["CASES"]=tab["CASES"].fillna(0)
tab["CASES"] = tab["CASES"].values.astype(int)

#######matplotlib########
x=tab["STATES"]
y=tab["CASES"]
plt.cla()
plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=len(y)/4)
plt.bar(x,y, color="blue")
plt.xticks(fontsize= 8,rotation='vertical')
plt.yticks(fontsize= 8)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) and [`barh`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barh.html#horizontal-bar-chart)

- `.read_html` will read all tables tags from a website and return a list of dataframes.
- `barh` will make horizontal instead of vertical bars, which is useful if there are a lot of bars.
- Make the plot longer, if needed. In this case, `(16.0, 10.0)`, increase `10`.
- I'd recommend using a log scale for x, because `Lagos` has so many cases compared to `Kogi`
- This doesn't put more space between the bars, but the formatted plot is more legible with its increased dimensions and horizontal bars.
- `.iloc[:36, :5]` removes some unneeded columns and rows from the dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# url
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_Nigeria'

# create dataframe list
dataframe_list = pd.read_html(url)  # this is a list of all the tables at the url as dataframes

# get the dataframe from the list
df = dataframe_list[2].iloc[:36, :5]  # you want the dataframe at index 2

# replace '-' with 0
df.replace('–', 0, inplace=True)

# set to int
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('int')

# plot a horizontal bar
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 10.0)
plt.style.use('ggplot')

p = plt.barh(width='Cases', y='State', data=df, color='purple')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Number of Cases')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Plot all the data in `df`

```py
df.set_index('State', inplace=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 14))
df.plot.barh()
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### 4 subplots

- `State` as index

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 14))
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns, 1):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i)
    df[col].plot.barh(label=col, color='green')
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```